# JS How can I improve this Arrary -> Object function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build an object of empty arrays from an array of values I wish to use as the new object keys.

```
const FILTERS = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

```
createFilteringObject() === { foo: [], bar: [], baz: []}
```

```
function createFilteringObject() {
    const filterObj = {}

    for (const filterCategory of FILTERS) {
        filterObj[filterCategory] = [];
    }

    return filterObj;
}
```

I want to improve my ES6 knowledge. Does anyone have a neat way of doing this in one line?

Comment: Look into `array.reduce()` - you can nail this much more concisely

Comment: I can post the answer for the points but you probably want to solve the problem yourself...

Comment: @TKoL Solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`FILTERS.reduce((a,b) => Object.assign(a, { [b]: []}), {})`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the new [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), but be sure to check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility). This one in conjunction with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) could do the job:

```js
const FILTERS = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

let res = Object.fromEntries(FILTERS.map(x => [x, []]));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with post-ES6, use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```
Object.fromEntries(FILTER.map(key => [key, []]))
```